# How to pause system on same thread

Tags: java, android

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){


    @Override
    public void run(){


        Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,100,100,true);

        ib.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);


         ib.setImageBitmap(b);

    }
},1000);
```

Comment: Your question is not specific and understandable.

Comment: Are you looking for `Thread.sleep(1000);`?

Comment: Within a recursive function it seems to unwind all the calls made in the handler only  after the stack has popped empty

Comment: Thread.sleep does the same